# iOS Mapkit - How to filter annotations (show/hide)?

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit, pins

So I have 4 different types of annotations that show specific pins (i.e. colors). I want to be able to have a segmented control that allows users to show/hide these annotations by type.

Is there a simple way to hide specific annotations on command? Or do I really have to remove, then rebuild the annotations with only the ones I want shown?

This app could potentially have hundreds or thousands of pins, all of which will be 1 of the 4 different types of pins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

Basically when creating the annotations, I store them in different arrays (for each type).

```
//Store Annotation in Array
    [type1Array addObject:annotation];
```

Then, when my button is pressed to filter them, I use the following:

```
    [_mapView removeAnnotations:type1Array];
    [_mapView addAnnotations:type2Array];
```

This seems to work fine and doesnt cause problems with duplicating annotations. I used an NSLog to output the _mapView.annotations.count to verify that the annotations were duplicating.

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Is it better to remove them or hide them?  [[_mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:YES];